# Zutaten and Ingredienzien

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which one is the right word for ingredients?

1. Ich habe die Zutaten für den Geburtstagskuchen gekauft.
2. Ich habe die Ingredienzen für den Geburtstagskuchen gekauft.

Comment: Beides richtig, aber der zweite Satz ist unüblich und wird von weniger gut gebildeten Menschen vielleicht auch nicht verstanden. In meinem Sprachgebrauch verwendet allenfalls der Apotheker Ingredenzien, der Koch aber Zutaten.

Comment: I believe they're both the word for ingredients, but Zutaten is much more common. For example, Ingredienz is not in my Bedeutungswörterbuch and you can see the Google Trends graph-- http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Ingredienzen%2C%20Zutaten

Comment: There's a little mistake in the word "Ingredienzen". The correct spelling is "Ingredienzien".
As you can see, we don't use that word very often^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prepare a meal, use *Zutaten*. If you want go into magic potion business, your grimoire will surely name different *Ingredienzien*. The latter translation is sometimes also used when it comes to (handmade/expensive/alternative) cosmetics, traditional druggist products or esoteric stuff. For products other than (home-made) food, you can also use *Inhaltsstoffe*.